# Include() works with bloginfo() but yields fatal error with get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Tags: wordpress

My `include()` works via `include(bloginfo('template_directory') . '/home_bloc_horaires.php');` (although this displays the path on the screen which I obviously don't want).

However `include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/home_bloc_horaires.php');` fails and yields errors:

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
Warning: include(http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/mirail/wp-content/themes/mmt-2014/home_bloc_horaires.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/mirail/wp-content/themes/mmt-2014/home_bloc_horaires.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
```

Yet, `echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/home_bloc_horaires.php';` displays a valid, functional path. Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

`get_stylesheet_directory()` returns the directory path(File System Path) .
`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns URI of directory(Web path)